# How to get transaction fee info using Python from an Electrum server?

Tags: transaction-fees, electrum, python, python-bitcoinlib, electrum-server

I can get a raw transaction and parse it using `electrum` and `bitcoinlib` fairly easily:

```
import bitcoinlib

from electrum.daemon import Daemon
from electrum.simple_config import SimpleConfig

class TxInfoClient:
    """Transaction info client"""

    def __init__(self):
        common_config = parse_config()
        electrum_config = SimpleConfig(
            {"testnet": False, "server": common_config["electrum"]["server"]}
        )
        self.daemon = Daemon(electrum_config, listen_jsonrpc=False)

    def get_tx(self, tx_id):
        """Returns a bitcoinlib.transactions.Transaction:
        https://bitcoinlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/bitcoinlib.transactions.html#bitcoinlib.transactions.Transaction
        """
        raw_tx = self.daemon.network.run_from_another_thread(
            self.daemon.network.get_transaction(tx_id)
        )
        return bitcoinlib.transactions.Transaction.parse_hex(raw_tx)
```

However, the resulting Transaction object won't contain fee information because it [isn't possible to calculate Bitcoin Tx fees from a single transaction](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73518/how-to-get-transaction-fee-from-raw-transaction).

I could go through and query input transactions manually, as suggested in that link. However, I am looking for a simple solution that uses well established and maintained libraries to do it.

Is there a way to make this happen using `bitcoinlib` and `electrum`, or other mainstream libraries?